# What am i missing in the controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This ruby class throws me an error  User is the name of the table, so i don't know why it says that there's an error in the index method cause is suposed that Users.all have to return nil
C:/ProyectosRails/gag_cf/app/models/user.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

Extracted source (around line #7):

```
# GET /users.json
def index
@users = User.all
end
```

This is the controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end


  def show
  end


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        authenticates_with_sorcery!
          validates_confirmation_of :password, message: "Both fields must match", if :password
     end
```

Comment: The problem appears to be in your user model not your controller, although if you pasted the complete source of your controller there, you're missing and 'end' after the destroy action

Comment: It says the error is in the model.  Where is the model code

Comment: @rainkinz 
no i didn't pasted the complete source
look here is the user model

     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       authenticates_with_sorcery!
       validates_confirmation_of :password, message: "Both fields        must match", if :password
      end

Comment: Put that in your question so it can be formatted. The error message is pretty explicit about where the error is (or at least begins), it only makes sense to include it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma(`,`). Remove this extra `,`. Below code is taken from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333992/what-am-i-missing-in-the-controller/22334160#comment33941690_22333992) of OP.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  authenticates_with_sorcery! 
  validates_confirmation_of :password, message: "Both fields must match", if :password
                                                                   # see|
end
```

Comment: Thanks! now i have an error with the if @user.save i'll try to fix it

Comment: Remove the code from your post. and put there the one you gave in the comment. @user3407533. Otherwise you would get much more down-votes. Which will prevent you to post any more questions.

Comment: @user3407533 What's the reason to unaccept this answer ?